# Splunk field extraction with square brackets [ ]

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to parse the below sample using Delimiters, could anyone help with the extraction. Delimiters don't seem to work for this. Can someone help with Regex commands?

`[2021-05-07T20:54:50.6222+10:00] [BDF] [ERROR:32] [BD99999] [security2] [client_id: 10.10.18.236] [host_id: google.com ] [host_addr: 10.10.05.11] [pid: 5397] [tid: 139783720359680] [user: apaapp] [ecid: 005kRh1ly^x8dpK_yTk3yW0001K80002jb] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: google:4445] [client 0.10.18.236] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "^[\\\\d.:]+$" at REQUEST_HEADERS:Host. [file "/apps/vbgrt/bdf/Google/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bdf_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/BDF/instances/bcp/crs-rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "735"] [id "920350"] [msg "Host header is a numeric IP address"] [data"10.10.05.11:4445"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_PQR/3.3.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_PQR"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "google"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "HTjues090uwmX0Cz1kLVwAAAIw"]`

Comment: [`\[([^\[\]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/LjOZzX/1)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this search-time, or in [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf)? Is the data *always* formatted like the above? How many fields do you want/need to extract? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to extract every single key value item in square brackets into a variable named by the key?

Answer (score -1):

```
\[(?<field1>[^\[\]]+)]
```

Please try this Regex, hope it works for you.